# Limit of positive sum is negative? Related to polylgarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, special-functions

So my initial point of confusion is on
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \   x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\cdots
\end{equation}
which we recognise as 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ -\text{log}(1-x)=-\infty
\end{equation}
by properties of the complex logarithm. Firstly how can we resolve our intuition, the sum of positive quantities taken to infinity is negative infinity?

My interest in this question is that I wish to understand why the limit of the polylogarithm, $\text{Li}_{n}(x)$ (of which $\text{Li}_{1}(x)=-\text{log}(1-x)$  ), is -$\infty$ for positive integer $n$ as $x$ goes to infinity. One of my issues is that the branch cut for the polylogarithm is placed on the positive real axis (where I'm interested) in most definitons, can this simply be moved to the negative real axis as for $\text{log}(1-x)$?

Comment: For the polylogarithm case, one has to specify the definition to be used for the analytic continuation together with branch cuts. One possibility to get the values on $\mathbb{R}_{<-1}$ is to use the functional relation $$ \operatorname{Li}_n \left( z \right)+(-1)^n \operatorname{Li}_n \left( 1/z \right) =-\frac{(2\pi i )^n}{n!} B_n\left( \frac12+ \frac{\ln(-z)}{2\pi i}\right),$$
where $B_n$'s denote Bernoulli polynomials, and the standard branch cuts are used. The result that you want to prove follows easily (also in the case $n=1$).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Compute the radius of convergence of the series. Can we consider limit in infinity for this series?

Comment: Of course, convergence is only for |x|<1. It is essentially the same as applying limits to the expression for sum of a geometric series.

Do you happen to know where the polylogarithm limit comes from though?